# create json string on client side

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create the JSON string / object that is equivalent to the following data on the server side. can somebody help?

```
Public Shared Function GetData() As List(Of Employee)
    Dim list As New List(Of Employee)()

    Dim newEmployee As New Employee()

    newEmployee.EmployeeID = "1"
    newEmployee.FirstName = "Sridhar"
    newEmployee.Title = "Programmer"
    newEmployee.BirthDate = "8/10/1979"
    newEmployee.TitleOfCourtesy = "Programmer"
    list.Add(newEmployee)
    Return list
 End Function
```

Employee is a class with the properties EmployeeId, FirstName, Title, Birthdate, TitleOfCourtesy.

Thanks,
sridhar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that in Javascript there is no concept of a class, only objects. This also carries over into JSON. Look at this:

```
{"Employee" : 
     {
        "EmployeeID":"1",
        "FirstName":"Sridhar",
        etc...
     }
 }
```

If you look at the first line, the "Employee" symbol does absolutely nothing for the JSON. Remember that we're dealing with ONLY objects.

Thats why this works, like you said.

```
[
{"EmployeeID":1,
"LastName":"Duggireddy",
"FirstName":"Sridhar",
"Title":"Programmer",
"TitleOfCourtesy":"Programmer",
"BirthDate":new Date(303091200000)}
]
```

To make this programatically, declare your employee objects, and just add them into an array, like so:

```
var employees = [];
employees.push(employee1); // you would use a loop, of course
employees.push(employee2);
...
var jsonString = parser.toJSON(employees); // or whatever you use.
```

That should give you a list of objects. Always ignore the class in JSON... .NET during the deserialization will attempt to coerce the object into that particular class. You only have problems if this fails - maybe because a variable is missing or of the wrong type.

Comment: thank you for the explanation. It worked perfectly. I didn't use parser.toJSON though. is it a standard javascript function or a plugin that I need to include?

Comment: No, what JSON parser you use depends on your library... you'll probably have to look at the docs for the correct method to use.

Answer (score 0):

It will look like

```
{"Employee" : 
     {
        "EmployeeID":"1",
        "FirstName":"Sridhar",
        etc...
     }
 }
```

[Reference](http://www.json.org/example.html)

I believe multiple instances of Employee in the JSON would look like this:

```
{"Employee" : 
     {
        "EmployeeID":"1",
        "FirstName":"Sridhar",
        etc...
     },
     {
        "EmployeeID":"2",
        "FirstName":"Joe",
        etc...
     }
 }
```

Maybe that is what you need?

Comment: I tried this before but it didn't work. The list that the server side is returning is array of employees.

Comment: That should work.  It's an object with the primary key "Employee" whose value is an object itself with various properties such as "EmployeeID" and "FirstName".  That JSON is correct, so I don't know why it would return an array, unless it's your server side code...

Comment: if I set the vairable as 
    [{"EmployeeID":1,"LastName":"Duggireddy","FirstName":"Sridhar","Title":"Programmer","TitleOfCourtesy":"Programmer","BirthDate":new Date(303091200000)}]; 
it is working. But I am not sure how to create this programmatically.

Comment: > I believe multiple instances of Employee in the JSON would look like
> this:
>
> <snip/>

Actually, you're looking for an array.  You can't use multiple objects successively as values like that. Here is the corrected code using arrays for multiple employees:

{"Employee": [{"EmployeeID": "1", "FirstName": "Sridhar"}, {"EmployeeID": "2", "FirstName": "Joe"}]}

Also, because arrays are indexed using integers, you could completely remove the EmployeeID field and just use integers for the EmployeeID field.

Comment: @Dustin - thanks, I wasn't 100% sure on the syntax.
@Sridhar - I've never created JSON client side like this, so I'd think you'd either have to manually build it up by creating a long string, or (probably an easier option) use something already made to do it like Sakabako suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [JSON.NET](http://www.codeplex.com/Json) and let it handle encoding/decoding for you?

Answer (score 0):

There's a good jQuery plugin for JSON. It lets you go from a JavaScript object to JSON very easily.

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/